# Learn and understand the full stack

Tags: language-agnostic, frameworks

I have been struggling with an idea for a few weeks and wanted to see if someone can help me out here.

Programming today is full of abstractions, and people who do not understand the abstractions, do not truly understand the reason or design than went into building that abstraction/layer/framework and will struggle as soon as they step outside the comfort zone.

I was wondering if there is a learning resource that goes about teaching programming in an incremental fashion. This will lead to understanding the full stack.

1. take a small problem
2. implement a simple solution
3. talk about the the solution and the designs used
4. convert the solution into a framework or utility of some sort
5. now extend the problem space and repeat from step 2.

This way when someone then picks up any framework/library, they can easily visualize the problems the framework is trying to solve, the design decisions taken and the reasons thereof.

*[Added to clarify the intent]*

Based on the answers and comments below, I want to clarify that I want to move further up the stack. Building your own ORM to understand ORM better, same goes for ActiveRecord, IOC container, data binding, templating engine, and the host of other magic/glue/plumbing we use day-to-day.

Thanks.

Comment: added an answer with sample resource:  http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX15

Comment: Django book follows the pattern you described to teach about Django Python web-framework http://djangobook.com/en/1.0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the source. It is a good idea to build something you want to understand, but you can enhance your understanding of concepts significantly by looking at how something is built. This is especially true for infrastructure pieces (ORM/DI/Templating) which you seem to be interested in.

Get the software to build on your machine, attach a debugger and trace through the code. This is pretty easy for C#/Java with a good IDE. For dynamic languages like Python and Ruby, it takes a good editor and a lot of grepping.

If it is a good software package, it will usually have tests. Tests are a great place to start digging into code. They usually make clear the intent of the code, and also provide you a logical starting point to peel off the layers and actually peek under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I recommend : Have a brush with assembly (just one book or one month is enough). Have a good strong review of C++ (hopefully it will teach you some of C as well). Now the world is yours. Python is made in C/C++ , Object C is pretty close to c++, .NET is in C++ and C#/VB.NET , The windows API is oriented for C. 

I picked C# as my abstract language of choice after this by the way.

Comment: This is discussed in an episode of "This Developer's Life" : http://thisdeveloperslife.com/post/1361199493/1-0-6-abstraction . This is the path of http://www.charlespetzold.com/ albeit all the short brushes I recommend he did for many many years :) I have a deep respect for his genius.

Comment: i started from Pascal, then C, then ASM, then C again(this time with more courage) then C++ and now i switch to PHP + C#. But yeah, one should start low-level and go up through the abstraction layers

Comment: I am pretty sure that if a guy knows C that is as abstract as he needs . Assembly is really useful when you do some micro-controller programming but in modern OSes it doesn't really matter.

Comment: No there is no learning resource specifically for this. Most algorithms are presented in at least one language (even Knuth chose assembly http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth). That and there are way to many algorithms and we are still learning new things all the time. e.g. ORMs were all the heat a year ago .... now we are questioning if ORM is the best thing ever or we should do NoSQL to begin with? I can see that you want a kind of wikipedia for programming methods / api designs alone. Well there isn't any :)

Answer (score 0):

Build a fully functional compiler from scratch in a systems language like C or C++. Maybe it isn't the full stack, but it's a large part of it. This is something I want to do as well. If only I could find the time and space.

Answer (score 0):

The best example of the sort of learning resources I am seeking is the MIX session by Rob Eisenberg on "BUILD YOUR OWN MVVM FRAMEWORK". It goes step by step on explaining the pattern and also implementing it at the same time, attacking one problem area at a time.

http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX15

Hope there are more out there.